# How can I make a sticky table header?

Tags: css

I have a table and I would like to make the header sticky.

I am using the following code:

```
.table-2 thead th {
  position: sticky !important;
  position: -webkit-sticky !important;
  top: 0 !important; 
}
.table-2 {
    position: relative !important;
      overflow-x: visible !important;
}
```

On this page: https://tfc.eu.com/smalley-spirolox-retaining-rings/spirolox-retaining-rings-selection-guide/

But it's not working.

What is wrong?

Comment: There is some overflow:hidden or auto in the way. try and test :`*{overflow:visible!important}
 table thead th {position:sticky!important;top:0;background:hotpink}` and you should see sticky in action. You have to dig in your code to find where overflow is unnecessary and where it breaks it (you also have plenty position:relative)

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand:

> The issue boils down to the fact that stickiness requires position:
> relative to work and that doesn’t apply to  and  in the CSS
> 2.1 spec.

(Source: https://css-tricks.com/position-sticky-and-table-headers/)

Comment: Hi, I used this code (as per that link)...

    table {
       text-align: left;
      position: relative;
      border-collapse: collapse; 
    }
    
    th {
      background: white;
      position: sticky;
      top: 0; /* Don't forget this, required for the stickiness */
      box-shadow: 0 2px 2px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    }

And it didn't work. Any suggestions?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

First try to give table tag position relative in the last set position sticky to th:

```
.table-2 {
   position: relative;
   overflow-x: visible;
}
.table-2 th {
   position: sticky !important;
}
```

you only have th in each table so no need thead

Comment: I've tried this code and it hasn't worked. Any suggestions?

Comment: use this code sample :https://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/PrJdxb/